# Galois Group of $f(x)=x^4 - 10 x^2 + 1$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

I am trying to calculate the Galois group of $f(x)=x^4 - 10 x^2 + 1\in\mathbb Q[x]$ over $\mathbb Q$.

In my notes it says that the four roots are $\pm\sqrt 2\pm\sqrt 3$. So the splitting field of $f(x)$ is clearly $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$. Now I can send $\sqrt 2\mapsto \pm \sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3\mapsto \pm\sqrt 3$, which gives me $4$ possibilites, and it is easy to see that Gal$(f)=$Gal$(\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3):\mathbb Q)=C_2\times C_2$.

But how can I see that the roots are $\pm\sqrt 3\pm\sqrt 3$ ? If I just start by rearranging the terms of $x^4 - 10 x^2 + 1=0$, then I get $(x^2-5)^2-24=0$ and consequently $x=\pm\sqrt{5\pm2\sqrt 6}$. These roots are not as easy to work with as the first ones. So how do I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$(a\pm b)^2=a^2+b^2\pm 2ab.$$
Letting $a=\sqrt{3}$, $b=\sqrt{2}$, we have
$$(\sqrt{3}\pm\sqrt{2})^2=5\pm2\sqrt{6}.$$

Comment: @Thomas: Now I don't know what your exact question is. Are you interested in the Galois group of the specific polynomial $x^4-10x^2+2$ or the general situation?

Comment: Originally I was interested in a more general approach, but then I got stuck trying calculate this particular Galois group. Sorry for the confusion, I will re-edit my first post so that your answer fits my original question.

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you. A comment to your general question: I think your method to calculate the Galois group of $x^4-10x^2+1$ is hard to be generalized, and a general approach to finding the Galois group of a polynomial seems hopeless. For [quartic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function), there exists a general way by introducing a [resolvent cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Galois_theory_and_factorization). However, for a specific quartic polynomials, the calculation still could be more complicated than the example $x^4-10x^2+1$.